# How do i check if file/item exist already in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The variable `fi` (FileInfo[]) contain for example 10 files.
I want to loop over the files and check if each one of them already exist in the `List<string> AnimatedGifFiles` if the first file in `fi` not exist in the List keep loop over and check for the second files and third and all the files in `fi` and then only continue.

The way I did it now if the first or second file not exist the program continue.

```
if (ToCreate == false)
{
    combined = Path.Combine(sf, fi[simtest].FullName);

    if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count == 0)
    {
        AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < AnimatedGifFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!AnimatedGifFiles[i].Contains(combined))
        {
            AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);//last_file);
        }
    }
    simtest += 1;
}
```

Comment: why can't bool the value by list.Exists()

Comment: You know that you can't modify `AnimatedGifFiles` while you're looping thru it?

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to add all of the file names from `fi` that currently don't exist is `AnimatedGifFiles` to that list. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you have a list, and want to loop through it, I would always recommend using `foreach (string foo in foolist)`.

However, if you want to check if the string combined already exists in your list, you can simply check it with `if (list.Contains(combined))` so looping through it should be unneccessary in your case.

This should work for you:

```
        if (ToCreate == false)
        {
            combined = Path.Combine(sf, fi[simtest].FullName);

            if (AnimatedGifFiles.Contains(combined) == false)
                AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);

            simtest ++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the shortest way to produce a list of unique filenames from the input given is to do it through [Union IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) extension

```
AnimatedGifsFiles = AnimatedGifsFiles.Union(fi.Select(x => x.FullName)).ToList();
```

> UNION Produces the set union of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer

Let me also point to a possible problem in your code above. Using Path.Combine to create a new path from the variable sf plus the FileInfo.FullName is quite wrong. The FullName property already contains the path name.

Comment: You have to write x.FullName insted of x.Name

Comment: @gabba you are right, a copy/paste error from a simplified test

Comment: @gabba now that you let me look at it. Something is not quite right in the OP code. Path.Combine with the FullName seems to be wrong

Comment: Yep 8). Thank you. a copy/paste error from question

Answer (score 1):

Beter to use HashSet to know existance of some element:

```
    var AnimatedGifFiles = new HashSet<string>(
        new string[] {
            "file1",
            "file2"
    });

    foreach (var fileItem in fi)
    {
        combined = Path.Combine(sf, fileItem.FullName);
        var added = AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use...

```
   if (!AnimatedGifFiles.Contains(combined))
      AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);
```

instead of

```
 for (int i = 0; i < AnimatedGifFiles.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!AnimatedGifFiles[i].Contains(combined))
        {
            AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);//last_file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to add all of the file names from `fi` that currently don't exist is `AnimatedGifFiles` to that list. Is that right?

If so, this works:

```
AnimatedGifFiles
    .AddRange(
        fi
            .Select(x => x.FullName)
            .Where(x => !AnimatedGifFiles.Contains(x))
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray());
```

This is actually even nicer:

```
AnimatedGifFiles
    .AddRange(
        fi
            .Select(x => x.FullName)
            .Except(AnimatedGifFiles)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray());
```

Comment: @gabba - I added `.Distinct()` to remove the possibility of duplicates.